# simple character splitting is baffling me

Tags: r, strsplit

the split as shown below is driving me crazy...nee somehelp to spot where is the problem

```
> p5<-Data$poorcoverageusers[5]
> p5
[1] "405874050693761|405874004853834|405874056470063|405874055308702"
> strsplit(p5,"|")
[[1]]
 [1] "4" "0" "5" "8" "7" "4" "0" "5" "0" "6" "9" "3" "7" "6" "1" "|" "4" "0" "5" "8" "7" "4" "0" "0" "4" "8" "5" "3" "8" "3" "4" "|" "4" "0" "5"
[36] "8" "7" "4" "0" "5" "6" "4" "7" "0" "0" "6" "3" "|" "4" "0" "5" "8" "7" "4" "0" "5" "5" "3" "0" "8" "7" "0" "2"

> typeof(Data$poorcoverageusers[5])
[1] "character"
```

i wanted it to be splitted by "|"... so output should have been 405874050693761 405874004853834 405874056470063 405874055308702

what is he mistake i m making..

thnks for help

r

Comment: escape "|", Try,  `strsplit(p5,"\\|")[[1]]`

Comment: use `strsplit(p5,"\\|")` or `strsplit(p5,"[|]")`

Comment: thanks actually double escape....i was doing single.. thnks again

Comment: you can also use `scan(text=p5,sep="|",)`

Answer (score 0):

```
library(stringr)

s <- "405874050693761|405874004853834|405874056470063|405874055308702"

str_split(s, fixed("|"))                # returns a list of character vectors
# [[1]]
# [1] "405874050693761" "405874004853834" "405874056470063" "405874055308702"

str_split(s, fixed("|"), simplify = T)  # returns a character matrix
#      [,1]              [,2]              [,3]              [,4]             
# [1,] "405874050693761" "405874004853834" "405874056470063" "405874055308702"
```